# The GET method is not supported for this route.Supported methods: HEAD

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing

I just installed Laravel 8 and created new controller and route. when i try to use new route that i created which is working fine but **route('/')** is not working. giving me error
**The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: HEAD.**

> route/web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('login', [LoginController::class,'loginShow'])->name('login');
```

> LoginController

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
     function loginShow(){
        return view('Login.login');
     }
}
```

> Route List
> [image]

Problem Detail :
here i have 2 routes  1) **mydomin** or **mydomin/**  2) **myDomian/login**

here **myDomian/login** is working as i want but when i try to use  **mydomin** then i am getting [image]

many time i face thing problem but sometime i fix anyway. But i want to know its real reason why it happen? so next time i will take case self. here **mydomin** is GET method route and i delcleared in web.php as GET. so why it is telling it is HEAD not get? Also note that before create a new route it was working in same way. so why now not? please tell me reason of this.

Comment: How you use this route login?

Comment: can you show us which part you call this route?

Comment: i am calling route  like this way  :: http://127.0.0.4/Development/Learn%20Angular/angular10/Auth-Angular/JWT-Auth/backend/laravel/

Comment: http://127.0.0.4/Development/Learn%20Angular/angular10/Auth-Angular/JWT-Auth/backend/laravel/login   --- login route

Comment: you run this url without ``php artisan serve`` or config with virtaulhost?

Comment: yes , without that.

Comment: yes it is working with  php artisan serve but without this not. why?

Comment: i mostly not use **php artisan serve**. and every time it work but why now? please tell me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228106/discussion-between-pankaj-kumar-and-sok-chanty).

Answer (score 0):

i got my solution using  `php artisan serve` . so after that it is start working. but i a could not understand why it is not working without **php artisan serve** .... if any one has any reason please tell us.